# Images are not loaded in react and also not giving error

Tags: reactjs, image

I am unable to load images despite of correct src given can anyone tell *silly* mistake in it!

[image: Tree structure]

I am absolute noobie so what is thing I am doing wrong ? in react img tag `<img src={} />` this how i think codes are written in it!

Template.js Code

```
import React from 'react';
import './Template.css';

function Template ()  {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="shape header-shape-one">
                    <img src={"./shape1.jepg"} alt="shape"></img>
            </div> 

            <div className="shape header-shape-tow animation-one">
                    <img src={"./shape2.png"} alt="shape"></img>
             </div> 

             <div className="shape header-shape-three animation-one">
                    <img src={"./shape1.jepg"} alt="shape"></img>
             </div> 

             <div className="shape header-shape-fore">
                    <img src={"./shape4.png"} alt="shape"></img>
             </div>
           </div>
        );
}

export default Template;
```

**App.js Code**

```
import React from 'react';
import NAVBAR from './components/Navbar/navbar';
import Template from './components/shape/Template'

class App extends React.Component 
{
  render() 
  {
    return (
      <div>
      <Template />
        <NAVBAR />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for solution in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a folder inside the public folder called images and move all your images there. Then, when referencing the path for your images do it like this: `<img src="./images/shape1.jpg" alt="shape" />`